# a filed in class doesn't initialize in a python function

Tags: python, class, directory, path

I created a function that checking if a path is a directory.

The path is depend on a filed in class named "wafer_num".
The function returns me false, because the path it's getting is:
/usr/local/insight/results/images/toolsDB/lauto_ptest_s2022-08-09/w<class 'int'>

instead of: /usr/local/insight/results/images/toolsDB/lauto_ptest_s2022-08-09/w+int number

the whole path is constant until the int number that attached to the 'w' char in path.
for example: if wafer_num filed in class is: 2, than the path will be:

/usr/local/insight/results/images/toolsDB/lauto_ptest_s2022-08-09/w2

I'm initializing the class from another file. the initialization is working well because I have many other functions in my code that depends on this filed.

I'm attaching the function that making me troubles and the class too. many thaks:

```
# This is the other file that call a constructive function in my code:

import NR_success_check_BBs as check_BBs
# list of implemented recipes:
sanity = 'sanity_' + time_now + '_Ver_5.1'
R2M_delayer = 'R2M_E2E_delayer_NR_Ver_5.1'
R2M_cross_section = 'R2M_E2E_NR_Ver_5.1'

# ***********************************************************************************************
# ***********************************************************************************************

# the function set_recipe_name will create an object that contain all the data of that recipe
check_BBs.set_recipe_name(R2M_delayer)


# this function contain all the necessary functions to check the object.
check_BBs.success_check()

# EOF
# -------------------------------------------------------

# This is the code file [with constructive function attached] :

import datetime
import logging
import os.path
from pathlib import Path
import time

time_now = str(datetime.datetime.now()).split()[0]
log_file_name_to_write = 'test.log'
log_file_name_to_read = 'NR_' + time_now + '.log'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filename=log_file_name_to_write, filemode='a',format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
R2M_RecipeRun_path = '/usr/local/disk2/unix_nt/R2M/RecipeRun/'
R2M_dir = '/usr/local/disk2/unix_nt/R2M'
metro_callback_format = 'Metro_Reveal_' 

class recipe:
    name = ''
    script_name = ''
    wafer_num = int
    images = 0
    metrology_images = 0


images_output_dir_path = '/usr/local/insight/results/images/toolsDB/lauto_ptest_s/' + time_now + 'w' + str(recipe.wafer_num)


def set_recipe_name(name):
    recipe.name = name
    logging.info("Analyzing the recipe: " + recipe.name)

    if recipe.name == 'sanity_' + time_now + '_Ver_5.1':
        recipe.script_name = 'Sanity_CS.py'
        recipe.wafer_num = 1

    elif recipe.name == 'R2M_E2E_NR_Ver_5.1':
        recipe.script_name = 'R2M.py'
        recipe.wafer_num = 2

    elif recipe.name == 'R2M_E2E_delayer_NR_Ver_5.1':
        recipe.script_name = 'R2M_delayer.py'
        recipe.wafer_num = 3


# ***********************************************************************************************
# ***********************************************************************************************

# This is the function that makes my trouble: 

def is_results_images_directory_exist():
    images_directory_path = Path('/usr/local/insight/results/images/toolsDB/lauto_ptest_s' + time_now + '/w' + wafer_num)
    print(images_directory_path)
    is_directory = os.path.isdir(images_directory_path)
    print(is_directory)
    if not is_directory:
        logging.error("There is no images directory for the current recipe at results")
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a reasonable class definition to me. Why no `__init__`? Why a bunch of class variables that look like they should be instance variables?

Comment: In any case, **what did you expect** `wafer_num` to be, other than`'<class 'int'>'`?

Comment: any int number that called from outer file, such 1, 2 , 3 ...

Comment: This is a strange design. Anyhow, do a check on the type of wafer_num before using it to construct a path. If it is int type, carry on, else raise exception to the caller.

Comment: That's strange, i have other function that returning me other paths based on this filed

Comment: What do you mean "any int number that called from outer file, such 1, 2 , 3 " What "outer file"? Please be precise

Comment: I have a file that calling the code above. that other file, is calling a constructive function that based on the argument it gets, is setting all the fields in the class.
than, the function above is calling right after the constructive function

Im not running the original code file above, im running another file that calling it

Comment: @I'mnotarobot **please show us the actual code**. Note, your class *doesn't have a constructor* (not one that does anything useful, just the default one) you never defined one

Comment: I edited my post and now both codes are presented

Comment: You aren't using a constructor anywhere, you never instantiate your class. I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how instances are created - you create it using something like `MyClass(arg1, arg2)`

Comment: In any cas,e you must provide a [mcve], your not actually showing wher ethe `wafer_num` comes from. You used to have that simply set to the value right after you created the class, which wouldn't change after you updated the class

Comment: function set_recipe_name get a name as an argument, 
by this name, I'm building my class doesn't I?

or there is need to be a constructive function that I'm miss understood how to implement?